# PDO Foreach fetch loop returns first row with specific id and rest as false

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have problem where function is returning objects as false. This function first fetches list of all users in specific group then uses that array to fetch every message that each user has posted and should return all messages as one big message array. Feel free to correct title.

```
 public function listMessages($group_id){ 
   $db = initDb(); 
   $getGroupUsers = $db->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM in_group WHERE group_id = :group_id");
   $getGroupUsers->bindParam(":group_id", $group_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $getGroupUsers->execute();
   $users = $getGroupUsers->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $messages = array();
   foreach ($users as $item) {
     $getMessage = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM task_messages WHERE user_id = :user_id ORDER BY visited ASC");
     $getMessage->bindParam(":user_id", $item['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $getMessage->execute();                
     if($getMessage->rowCount() > 0){
       $message = $getMessage->fetchObject();
       array_push($messages, $message);
     }                
   }        
   return json_encode($messages);                       
 }
```

But for some reason it only fetches one message per each user. I tested this by adding 3 messages from same user and the calling this function.

[image: result as image]

But if I add message from another user

[image: result when adding another users message]

Here is my database shown as image below

[image: database image]

Comment: Have you checked the content of `$users`? Iam not too sure about it, but I think `$users = $getGroupUsers->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` actually returns an array like `array("user_id" => array(0=>ID1,1=>ID2,...))`.  Therefore you'd have to make the `foreach()`as `foreach($users['user_id'] as $item)`

Comment: @Jaspa I tried this but it resulted as an error. Undefined index: user_id.

Comment: Okay, then my image of this array seems wrong. But have you checked the content already? It might help you to find the problem

Comment: @Jaspa Content was alright. Problem was that I did not loop fetched user message array. All I needed to change is that when I got the users messages by user_id I added while loop to fetchObject on each of those rows and push the into $messages array. I updated answer, feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out! All I had to do is to loop users messages array once they were fetched and then push each of those separately into another array that got returned in the end.

```
while($row = $getMessage->fetchObject()){
       array_push($messages, $row);   
}
```

Here is the complete function.

```
public function listMessages($group_id){ 
        $db = initDb(); 
        $getGroupUsers = $db->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM in_group WHERE group_id = :group_id");
        $getGroupUsers->bindParam(":group_id", $group_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $getGroupUsers->execute();
        $users = $getGroupUsers->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $messages = array();
        foreach ($users as $item) {
            $getMessage = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM task_messages WHERE user_id = :user_id ORDER BY visited ASC");
            $getMessage->bindParam(":user_id", $item['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $getMessage->execute();                
            if($getMessage->rowCount() > 0){                                        
                while($row = $getMessage->fetchObject()){
                    array_push($messages, $row);   
                }                                 
            }

        }
        return json_encode($messages); 
}
```

Now returned array looks like this:

[image: returned array]

Answer (score 1):

The docs say for PDOStatement::fetchObject:

> Returns an instance of the required class with property names that correspond to the column names or FALSE on failure.

Saying it returns an instance of a class (stdclass in your case) but nothing about multiple instances or an array. You probally would have to loop over the result set till false is returned by fetchObject. Or use fetchAll like you do in the query above.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php

Comment: Yes, this almost works, but now results are in multiple arrays. Each user has their own array within $messages array where all messages are stored correctly.

Comment: `$queryResult = $getMessage->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); foreach($queryResult as $message) { array_push($messages, $message); }` Doesn't that work?